# Raise INVALID_CURSOR exception when you access the cursor variable %ROWCOUNT after the cursor is closed

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I am using the following table in oracle

```
 EMPNO ENAME                DEPTN JOB                  HIREDDATE     SALARY
------ -------------------- ----- -------------------- --------- ----------
   111 Narayan              R22   Electrical           26-DEC-99       5000
   108 Horen                P69   PWD                  10-DEC-95      10000
   130 Roy                  A13   Security             15-SEP-01      25000
   420 Roy                  D12   IT                   15-SEP-99       2500
   100 Allu                 A13   Security             26-JAN-15      15000
```

And I was trying to use the EName to rowcount.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     temp varchar(20);
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT EName into temp from Employee01;
  5     dbms_output.put_line(temp);
  6  EXCEPTION
  7     WHEN too_many_rows THEN
  8     dbms_output.put_line('error trying to SELECT too many rows');
  9  END;
 10  /
```

I was trying to modify this code.

Comment: I don't think this is the code that's producing that error. Where's your use of `%ROWCOUNT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it would help if you posted code you *modified*, not something that is irrelevant to the question.

Here you go:

- line #15 - cursor is closed
- line #17 - using `c1%rowcount` on closed cursor
- lines #19-21 - handling `INVALID_CURSOR` exception; I'm just displaying a message, you'd probably do something *smarter*

---

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    cursor c1 is
  3      select empno, ename, job
  4      from emp
  5      where deptno = 10;
  6    c1r     c1%rowtype;
  7    l_cnt   number;
  8  begin
  9    open c1;
 10    loop
 11      fetch c1 into c1r;
 12      exit when c1%notfound;
 13      dbms_output.put_line(c1r.ename ||' - '|| c1r.job);
 14    end loop;
 15    close c1;
 16
 17    l_cnt := c1%rowcount;
 18
 19  exception
 20    when invalid_cursor then
 21      dbms_output.put_line('INVALID_CURSOR has been raised');
 22  end;
 23  /
CLARK - MANAGER
KING - PRESIDENT
MILLER - CLERK
INVALID_CURSOR has been raised

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```